# Can I scrape only elements that DON'T have a specific attribute?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In bs4, I want to apply a filter to scrape elements which do not have a specific attribute. It is hard to explain so consider this example:

There are 5 'div' elements. 4 of them have a 'class' and 'id' attribute, and the 5th have 'class', 'id', and 'style' attribute. I want to scrape only the first 4.

I know I can use `soup.find_all('div', {'class': '<class-name>', 'id': '<id>'}`  to apply filters for attributes that I want, but can I apply an additional filter for attributes I don't want.

See the example HTML code below:

[image: Example code]

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS Selector `:not()`, You can get this result like

```
soup.select('div:not(div[style="display: none;"])')
```

`:not()` indicate Selects every element that is not a div[style="display: none;"] element